# bootstrap - dropdown options don't change design

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on implementing Bootstrap 3.3.5 on an existing website.

Among other things, I'm going over all the form elements and add/change the classes to Bootstrap's ones.

Simply, taking this code:

```
<select id="mylist">
<option>...</option>
</select>
```

And having it like that:

```
<select id="mylist" class="form-control">
<option>...</option>
</select>
```

Therefore, when dealing with dropdown lists (SELECT elements), I add/change the class to "form-control" on each of them.

In those cases, the SELECT element itself turns into the Bootstrap look, but the options inside the list stay "regular".

I'm not talking about changing the normal list element into a DIV with "dropdownmenu" classes and so on, but only change the classes on the existing elements, as described.

In such a case, aren't the inside options supposed to change their look also, like the SELECT element itself does??
If so, what am I missing here that prevents these options to change also??

Comment: ' but the options inside the list stay "regular".', How do you mean? Is it possible to post an image of the "regular" options inside the list?

Comment: i don't believe its possible to style the actual option menu of a native select input.

Comment: Compare what you're seeing with the examples on the [Bootstrap web](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls) site. Looking in the web inspector, they only apply one style to the `<options>` tag.

Comment: Yes, in the native examples by Bootstrap, I do see that the options of the list are not styled as the list element itself (btw, that's what I mean by "regular"). But I clearly remember coming across a list with styled options in it, somewhere a few weeks ago, and it was definitely based on Bootstrap. Maybe that was a 3rd party plugin or something like that? If so, where can I find something like that?... Thanks.